# why does Enumerator include Enumerable

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation, enumerable

Dig this, here is a cool `Enumerator` (lazy sequence) from 1 to (the biggest `Float` Ruby can represent):

```
1.9.3-p327 :014 > e = (1..Float::INFINITY).each
```

Look at how we can grab the front of the sequence:

```
1.9.3-p327 :015 > e.first
 => 1 
1.9.3-p327 :016 > e.take(2)
 => [1, 2]
```

That's good stuff huh? I think so too. But then this:

```
1.9.3-p327 :017 > e.drop(2).first
```

Goes into lala land. And by that I mean it doesn't return in less than 5 seconds.

Oh here is a clue:

```
1.9.3-p327 :020 > p e.method(:drop)
#<Method: Enumerator(Enumerable)#drop>
```

It appears that the Enumerator (`e`) got its `#drop` method from the `Enumerable` (module) mixed in to the `Enumerator` (class). Now why in the world would Ruby go and mix `Enumerable` into `Enumerator` you ask? I do not know. But there it is, documented in both [`Enumerator` in Ruby 1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html) and [`Enumerator` in Ruby 2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerator.html).

The problem as I see it is that some methods defined in `Enumerable` work or kind of work on `Enumerator`. Examples include `#first` and `#take`. At least one other: `#drop` does not work.

It seems to me that `Enumerator` including `Enumerable` is a bug. What do you think?

PS notice that Ruby 2.0 defines `Enumerator::Lazy` (subclass of `Enumerator`) which defines a bunch of the `Enumerable` methods as always lazy. Something smells fishy here. Why mix in the non-lazy and in some cases broken methods (into `Enumerator`) only to turn around and provide lazy alternatives in a subclass (of `Enumerator`)?

See also:

```
1.9.3-p327 :018 > p e.method(:first)
#<Method: Enumerator(Enumerable)#first>
1.9.3-p327 :020 > p e.method(:drop)
#<Method: Enumerator(Enumerable)#drop>
```

Comment: Note that the `each` in `e = (1..Float::INFINITY).each` makes no difference. You should either leave it out, or replace it with `lazy`, depending on what you want exactly.

Comment: Thank you Marc-André. But there is no Enumerable#lazy in Ruby 1.9.3. That's only available in 2.0. I think one of my key misunderstandings was in assuming that #drop returned an Enumerator at all. For some reason, while both #drop and #take have trivial Enumerator implementations possible, neither returns an Enumerator at all! Even the fix for [Ruby Bug #7715 "Lazy enumerators should want to stay lazy"](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7715) fails to fix those. Come to think of it, those cannot be "fixed" since doing so would break code that relies on those returning Arrays!

Comment: Indeed, `drop` is "eager". BTW, you can play with `lazy` in any version of Ruby with `require 'backports/2.0.0/enumerable/lazy'`

Answer (score 3):

That's a design choice that is common to many other collection frameworks as well.

Ruby's collection operations are not type-preserving. They *always* return an `Array`, regardless of what type of collection they were called on. That's also what, for example, .NET does, except there the type is always `IEnumerable`, which is both more useful (because more things can be represented as an `IEnumerable` than as an `Array`, e.g. infinite sequences) and at the same time less useful (because the interface of `IEnumerable` is much smaller than that of `Array`, so there are less operations you can do on it).

This allows Ruby's collection operations to be implemented *once*, without duplication.

It also means that it's very easy to integrate your own collections into Ruby's collection framework: just implement `each`, mixin `Enumerable` and you are done. If a future version of Ruby adds a new collection method (e.g. `flat_map` in Ruby 1.9), you don't have to do *anything*, it just works with your collection, too.

Another design choice would be to make all collection operations type-preserving. So, all collection operations return the type they were called on.

There are some languages which do this. It is, however, implemented by copy&pasting all collection methods into all collection classes, i.e. with massive code duplication.

This means that if you want to add your own collection to the collection framework, you have to implement every single method of the collection protocol. And if a future version of the language adds new methods, then you have to release a new version of your collection.

Scala 2.8's collection framework was the first time that someone figured out how to do type-preserving collection operations without code duplication. But that was long after Ruby's collection framework was designed. When Ruby's collection framework was designed, it was simply not yet known how to do type-preserving collection operations without code duplication, and the designers of Ruby opted against duplication.

Starting with Ruby 1.9, there is actually some duplication. Some `Hash` methods were duplicated to return `Hash`es instead of `Array`s. And you already mentioned Ruby 2.0's `Enumerator::Lazy`, which duplicates many `Enumerable` methods to return `Enumerator::Lazy`.

It would be possible to use the same tricks Scala uses in Ruby, but it would require a complete rework of the collection framework, which would make every existing collection implementation obsolete. Scala was able to do this because at the time there was hardly any user base.

Comment: As usual, good answer. I wouldn't say that "They *always* return an `Array`" as can also return `Enumerator`s. The `Lazy` part is a bit misleading. The methods that act lazily are specialized, other are not. On the other hand, `Lazy#to_enum` is specialized and this nice trick means that any `Enumerable` method returning an `Enumerator` will return an `Enumerator::Lazy` when called on `Lazy`, without specialization. Details in bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7715

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first part:

> "Goes into lala land. And by that I mean it doesn't return in less
>   than 5 seconds."

That behavior seems consistent with what those methods are supposed to do:

```
take(n) → array # Returns first n elements from enum.
```

That means you just need to iterate up to N to return it.

```
drop(n) → array # #Drops first n elements from enum, and returns rest elements in an array.
```

That means that it needs the rest of the elements to able to return them. And since you upper bound is `Float::INFINITY` it behaves as such.

Source: [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html)

Comment: Thanks fmendez. Yep, I totally assumed (wrongly) that #take and #drop would return Enumerators. Now I understand why that would be bad. Lots of code relies on those returning Arrays.

Comment: Essentially, any old (pre 1.9) Enumerable method that did not take a block, could not be "upgraded" to return an Enumerator since there was no way for the caller to signal it wanted an Enumerator back. Enumerable#take and #drop don't take blocks so they could not be made to return Enumerators. Though of course Enumerator::Lazy#take and #drop do return Enumerators as expected.